# Do I need a visa if I want to visit Australia?

Tags: visas, paperwork, australia, refugees

I have a blue German travel document for refugees. I want to visit my uncle next summer. He lives in Sydney.

Comment: Why is this question being closed? I can understand what is being asked just fine, and there is already an answer to that question.

Answer (score 4):

[According to Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&SECTION=SR&COUNTRY=AU&ExpertMode22=&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines for visa information, a visa is required. You may travel on your German refugee travel document, but you'll need an Australian visa. This is also stated on [an Australian government website](http://www.border.gov.au/Lega/Lega/Mana/document).